# Is there a way to make collision necessary?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

This code I have for my player movement. Now I want to make the player (2d circle) stick to the path. I tried `OncollisionEnter2d` but it's detection wans't an obligation.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class player : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
        transform.Translate (new Vector2(moveHorizontal,moveVertical)*Time.deltaTime*speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: `OnCollisionEnter2d` is a method you can add to your own MonoBehaviours and which gets called when the object is involved in a 2d collision. It doesn't cause a collision to happen, it reacts to them. In order to answer your question, it would be helpful to know what exactly you mean with "the path". What kind of "path" are you talking about?

Comment: what you mean about sticking to path?

Comment: By stick to a path do you mean you want them to move with their position precisely constrained to a pre-defined path like, say, a train on a train track, or do you mean you want them to be able to move around inside a wider area but be limited on a how far they can go like, say, a car on a racetrack?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using colliders to stick to the path, use them to avoid the player to trespass the limit. Add colliders around the path and uncheck `Is Trigger`.